# Bash & TCL: Not getting the same output from the same function

Tags: arrays, bash, function, tcl, expect

I'm trying to get the nth argument of a list stored in an expect block.

```
#!/bin/bash

ReturnElementFromId() {
    local ix="$1" ; shift
    local arr=("$@")

    echo "${arr[$ix]}"
}

export -f ReturnElementFromId
ARRAY=("This is" "a" "test array !")

echo ">> $(ReturnElementFromId 2 "${ARRAY[@]}")"

expect -c "
    set output $(ReturnElementFromId 2 \"${ARRAY[@]}\")
    puts \">> \$output\"
"
```

When it comes to print the output, I get a different output from the "same command". Here is what it looks like:

```
>> test array !
>> a
```

I don't understand why outputs of the two same commands aren't both the same. Could someone help me?

Regards

Comment: Passing data from the shell to expect is best done through the environment. And you can't export arrays.

Comment: This is closely related to [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Comment: Keep in mind that the operating system's environment block has NULs separating each entry. What's the only character that can't be present inside the content of a string inside a shell array? Also a NUL. So there's no way you can stuff an array into a single environment variable literally -- you'd need to either have a separate environment variable per element, or come up with an escaping/unescaping mechanism. (The latter one you could actually do right now -- `array=( "This is" "a" "test array !" ); export array_b64=$(printf '%s\0' "${array[@]}" | base64 -w0)`)

Comment: ...and then to convert that back into an array (in a new enough bash to have `readarray -d`): `readarray -d '' array < <(base64 -d <<<"$array_b64")`

Comment: BTW, just to be **completely** clear, this has absolutely nothing whatsoever to do with tcl or expect; you'd have the exact same problem having one shell start another with no non-shell process between (so long as there's an `exec` boundary between them so variables are reinitialized from the environment rather than copied via a `fork()` from the parent).

Answer (score 1):

**Partial answer just to shed a light to this problem**

The first index of a Bash array is 0. Therefore, if your array indexes are `0 => "This is"`, `1 => "a"`, and `2 => "test array !"`. Therefore, your **first** bash call unrolls like this:

```
++ ReturnElementFromId 2 'This is' a 'test array !'
++ local ix=2
++ shift
++ arr=("$@")
++ local arr
++ echo 'test array !'
+ echo 'test array !'
>> test array !
```

Hence, to make your first call return the desired output you'd have to decrement the `ix` by 1.

Your **second** call to `ReturnElementFromId`, on the other hand, unrolls differently and your array is not passed to the function as you were expecting. Notice that your array is split into pieces here and thus processed as each word was a separate index from your array (try calling other indexes to check this out).

```
++ ReturnElementFromId 2 '"This' is a test array '!"'
++ local ix=2
++ shift
++ arr=("$@")
++ local arr
++ echo a
+ expect -c '
    set output a
    puts ">> $output"
'
>> a
```

I don't know much about `expect` calls, therefore, I would need more time to understand the proper way to make the **second** function call. Hope this partial answer helps you to solve your issue.

**Edit:** Variable unpack

Bash has different types of quotes, which tells how variables and special/meta characters should be interpreted [[1](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Quote.html#uh-2)]. The double quotes (`"`) are called **weak quotes** because they allow expansion of variables. Considering your question, take the following two calls to understand how bash interprets your function calls:

```
call-A$ echo ">> $(ReturnElementFromId 2 "${ARRAY[@]}")"
call-B$ echo ">> $(ReturnElementFromId 2 ${ARRAY[@]})"
```

`call-A` was provided by you and leaves the array outside the quotation, while `call-B` leaves it inside the quotation (i.e., between two `"`). In `call-A`, as the array is outside the double quotes, the bash doesn't expand its value before making the call to `ReturnElementFromId` thus preserving your intended structure. On the other hand, `call-B` expands your array before making the call to `ReturnElementFromId` hence dismantling your array into word-pieces.  Below you can see that in `call-A` your function call groups words with single quotes, while `call-B` has expanded the array (before the call) and is "sending" each character "separately". Check below the result from both calls:

```
call-A: ++ ReturnElementFromId 2 'This is' a 'test array !'
>> test array !
call-B: ++ ReturnElementFromId 2 This is a test array '!'
>> a
```

Even though they are not the same, `call-B` expansion directly relates to you `expect` expansion. As `expect` is using double quotes, bash is expanding your variable and dismantling your array.

Comment: Internally, expect indexes from zero. But that original script is a horrible mix of substitutions in several languages so it's pretty much anyone's guess as to what it will do.

Comment: @delirium, you should explain *why* the array is unpacked differently (short answer, quotes are escaped and array expansion is unquoted.)

Answer (score 0):

Passing data from the shell to expect is better done through the environment, otherwise you'll end up in quoting hell:

```
#!/bin/bash
...

export __element=$(ReturnElementFromId 2 "${ARRAY[@]}")

expect <<'END_EXPECT'
   set element $env(__element)
   puts ">> $element"
END_EXPECT
```

Using a **quoted here-doc** means you don't have to escape *anything* (not quotes, not variables) in the expect code from the shell.

With this method, there's no reason to export the function because you're not using it in expect -- frankly you don't need to export it in your code either. If you want expect to have access to the whole array, you'll need to rethink your strategy altogether: you can't export bash arrays.